# Why is CDF Player 10 so much bigger than previous version?

Tags: cdfplayer

CDF Player 9 took about 800 MB of disk space. Curent vesion takes more than 2 GB, is all of it necessary to run the program? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was answered at community by @AndreKuzniarek

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/288532?p_p_auth=qa7hhoyE

Here is the answer from above if you can't locate it as the thread is very long.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot for instant answer, that would make sense. I have a 32 GB tablet though.

Comment: The space is also non-negligible for SSD users.